# Deleting rows from one table in not in another table

Tags: sql

I am trying to delete a set of rows from TableA if they are not in TableB based off of a string of IDs.

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxX1g.png)

I have a string of IDs such as 1,2,3,4,5. I want to check tableB and if they dont exist delete the rows from tableA. In this case 2 and 4 would be deleted from Table A.

Comment: It would be best if you showed the sql code you have tried so far.

Comment: This is what i tried. Unfortunately, it deleted my entire table in QA the first time around. I also tried using                                                                                                                         Delete from TableA 
where ID NOT IN (Select ID from TableB where iProspect IN ( String )

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Here is a little more info. In my UI i am looping through and deleting rows from the subtable(TableB), If all the rows in table b for a specfic ID have been deleted then I want to delete the parent record from Table A Here is what i tried, I also tried to use Not Exists and that did not work either.                                                                                                                    Delete from TableA 
where ID NOT IN (Select ID from TableB where iProspect IN ( String ).

Answer (score 4):

The simple way would be (syntax depends on your particular brand of SQL) to use a subquery:

e.g.  `Delete from TableA where ID not in (select ID from TableB)`

Answer (score 0):

Your version of the query:

```
Delete from TableA
    where ID NOT IN (Select ID from TableB where iProspect IN ( @String );
```

Does not work.  The `IN` list consists of a single value, which happens to be a comma-delimited value.  In some SQL engines, you might even get a conversion error.

What you can do is use `LIKE`.  The exact syntax varies depending on the database, but this is typical syntax:

```
Delete from TableA
    where ID NOT IN (Select ID
                     from TableB
                     where CONCAT(',', @String, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', iProspect, ',%') );
```

Some databases might have better alternatives for dealing with strings.  In any database, you can use dynamic SQL to generate the statement.  If you know the `id`s are really lists of appropriate values, you can directly put them into the string.  With appropriate indexes, `IN` should have much better performance than `LIKE`.